# ASP Identity: Eager loading for User

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have added a propertry to IdentityUser named ClientID that related properly to table Clients by FK.

[image: AspNetUsers with ClientId FK]

Now i want to retrive user with his client name (from Clients table).
How do i create Include function for that in context.Users?

```
    public ActionResult Users(string filter = "all")
    {

       context = new IdentityContext();
        var allusers = context.Users.ToList();

        List<UserViewModel> model = allusers.Select(user => new UserViewModel { Username = user.UserName,FullName=user.FirstName + " "+ user.LastName, Id = user.Id, Roles = string.Join(",", UserManager.GetRoles(user.Id))}).ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```